# Вот, есть часть кода, хочу создать userbot, но он не отслеживает сообщения,нужно чтобы после команды, запускалась эта функция и подключался userbot

Tags: python, aiogram

```
    @dp.message_handler(commands='on')
 
async def m(message):
 
    user_id = message.from_user.id
 
    #  Подключаемся к БД
 
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
 
    #  Позволяет делать SQL запросы
 
    cur = conn.cursor()
 
    results_api_id = cur.execute("SELECT api_id FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
 
    api_id = results_api_id[0]
 
    results_api_hash = cur.execute("SELECT api_hash FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
 
    api_hash = results_api_hash[0]
 
    results_phone_number = cur.execute("SELECT phone_number FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
 
    phone_number = results_phone_number[0]
 
    results_sent_code = cur.execute("SELECT sent_code FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
 
    sent_code = results_sent_code[0]
 
    results_code = cur.execute("SELECT code FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
 
    code = results_code[0]
 
    print(code)
 
    await test(user_id, api_id, api_hash, phone_number, sent_code, message, code)
 

 

 
async def test(user_id, api_id, api_hash, phone_number, sent_code, message, code):
 
    user = Client(f's{user_id}', api_id, api_hash, phone_number)
 
    await user.connect()
 
    signed = await user.sign_in(phone_number, sent_code, code)
 
    print(signed)
 
    if signed:
 
        await message.reply('Подключено')
 
    else:
 
        await message.reply('Ошибка')
 
 
    @user.on_message(filters.me)
 
    def qwe(client, message):
 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Comment: Что за userbot? Что за класс Client? Как воспроизвести ваш пример?

Comment: aiogram и pyrogram, мне нужно чтобы бот aiogram создавал client в pyrogram и по команде, например ВКЛ подключал пользователю userbot